# How to configure Apache to reject (example) http://192.168.1.1 and accept only virtual hosts like http://www.example.com

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, iptables

I tried to search for a solution on this but didn't know how to frame the query to get my answer.

I want to block anyone from probing my server by IP urls (like http://192.168.1.1  -- any public IP address) while allowing properly URLs to my server (proper like http://www.example.com).

I feel there are four ways:

1. Create a virtual host entry in httpd.conf file that "traps an IP url.
2. Create a mod_rewrite entry to rewrite IP url that also "traps" it.
3. Create an IPTABLES entry that is capable of detecting IP urls and dropping those connection requests.
4. Do nothing because nothing can be done.

Which of the three (or recommend alternative) would be the best way to handle it.  How woudl I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple. Set the following as the VERY FIRST virtual host:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory "/path/to/root/site">
    AllowOverride All
    Options None
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from none
    Allow from all
    php_admin_value open_basedir /path/to/root/site
</Directory>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/root/site"
    ServerName NX-DOMAIN
</VirtualHost>
```

Inside of the /path/to/root/site, just make a simple .html file or something saying "404 Not Found" or even pop in a .htaccess redirect or something.

For your real sites, add these as the second, third, fourth, etc... virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory "/path/to/real/site1/">
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
    ServerAdmin you@domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/real/site1"
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com
    php_admin_value open_basedir /path/to/real/site1
</VirtualHost>
```

That way, any request to a domain you don't host (if someone points their domain to your IP or someone visits the raw IP) will get dumped to your custom error page.

Hope this helps.